# Run Powershell Script off Domain

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of automating some of our onboarding process for new users.

Our Helpdesk software can trigger powershell commands, however it is hosted externally through an MSP. The scripts need to be triggered from the C drive of the helpdesk software server, but as this server is not joined to our domain, I'm wondering how I can get the scripts to take action on our domain? For example, creating a new user account.

Any thoughts/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Would recommend asking on SuperUser.

Comment: Why is it important with the file system location when the script runs? And do you trust the MSP, eg. do they already have Domain Admin equivalent access to the domain?